# ignore "channel_layout" when working with multichannel audio in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm working with multichannel audio files (higher-order ambisonics), that typically have at *least* 16 channels.

Sometimes I'm only interested in a subset of the audiochannels (e.g. the first 25 channels of a file that contains even more channels).

For this I have a script like the following, that takes a multichannel input file, an output file and the number of channels I want to extract:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
infile=$1
outfile=$2
channels=$3

channelmap=$(seq -s"|" 0 $((channels-1)))

ffmpeg -y -hide_banner \
  -i "${infile}" \
  -filter_complex "[0:a]channelmap=${channelmap}" \
  -c:a  libopus -mapping_family 255 -b:a 160k -sample_fmt s16 -vn -f webm -dash 1 \
  "${outfile}"
```

The actual channel extraction is done via the [*channelmap* filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#channelmap), that is invoked with something like `-filter:complex "[0:a]channelmap=0|1|2|3"`

This works great with 1,2,4 or 16 channels.

However, it fails with 9 channels, and 25 and 17 (and generally anything with >>16 channels).

The error I get is:

```sh
$ ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -i input.wav  -filter_complex "[0:a]channelmap=0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16" -c:a libopus -mapping_family 255 -b:a 160k  -sample_fmt s16 -vn -f webm -dash 1 output.webm
Input #0, wav, from 'input.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:09.99, bitrate: 17649 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, 25 channels, s16, 17640 kb/s
[Parsed_channelmap_0 @ 0x5568874ffbc0] Output channel layout is not set and cannot be guessed from the maps.
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x5568874fff40] Error initializing filter 'channelmap' with args '0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16'
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument
```

So ffmpeg cannot guess the channel layout for a 17 channel file.
`ffmpeg -layouts` only lists channel layouts with 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 & 16.

However, I really don't care about the channel layout. The entire concept of "channel layout" is centered around the idea, that each audio channel should go to a different speaker.
But my audio channels are not speaker feeds at all.

So I tried providing explicit channel layouts, with something like `-filter_complex "[0:a]channelmap=map=0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16:channel_layout=unknown"`, but this results in an error when parsing the channel layout:

```sh
$ ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -i input.wav  -filter_complex "[0:a]channelmap=map=0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16:channel_layout=unknown" -c:a  libopus -mapping_family 255 -b:a 160k  -sample_fmt s16 -vn -f webm -dash 1 output.webm
Input #0, wav, from 'input.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:09.99, bitrate: 17649 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, 25 channels, s16, 17640 kb/s
[Parsed_channelmap_0 @ 0x55b60492bf80] Error parsing channel layout: 'unknown'.
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x55b604916d00] Error initializing filter 'channelmap' with args 'map=0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16:channel_layout=unknown'
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument
```

I also tried values like `any`, `all`, `none`, `0x0` and `0xFF` with the same result.
I tried using `mono` (as the channels are kind-of independent), but `ffmpeg` is trying to be clever and tells me that a *mono* layout must not have 17 channels.

I know that `ffmpeg` can handle multi-channel files without a layout.
E.g. converting a 25-channel file without the `-filter_complex "..."` works without problems, and `ffprobe` gives me an `unknown` channel layout.

So: how do I tell `ffmpeg` to just not care about the channel_layout when creating an output file that only contains a subset of the input channels?

Comment: Would slapping an "arbitrary layout" on the incoming channels work? https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation#Multiplechannellayouts

Comment: i'm not sure i understand the suggestion; I have no control over the input files (but could run them through ffmpeg in a preprocessing step).

Comment: I mean rather than attempting to mark the layout "unknown" you instead mark it with an arbitrary layout to satisfy it.

Comment: i guess that would be fine (a good candidate layout might be "mono+mono+mono+..."). i don't really understand how to do that though....

Comment: hmm, i tried something like `-filter_complex "pan=17c|c0=c0|c1=c1|c2=c2|c3=c3|c4=c4|c5=c5|c6=c6|c7=c7|c8=c8|c9=c9|c10=c10|c11=c11|c12=c12|c13=c13|c14=c14|c15=c15|c16=c16[a]" -map "[a]"` but that fails as well with an "Invalid channel layout" (it works with only 16 channels)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [Audio Channel Manipulation](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation) you could try splitting into `n` separate streams the `amerge` them back together:

```
-filter_complex "\
[0:a]pan=mono|c0=c0[a0];\
[0:a]pan=mono|c0=c1[a1];\
[0:a]pan=mono|c0=c2[a2];\
[0:a]pan=mono|c0=c3[a3];\
[0:a]pan=mono|c0=c4[a4];\
[0:a]pan=mono|c0=c5[a5];\
[0:a]pan=mono|c0=c6[a6];\
[0:a]pan=mono|c0=c7[a7];\
[0:a]pan=mono|c0=c8[a8];\
[0:a]pan=mono|c0=c9[a9];\
[0:a]pan=mono|c0=c10[a10];\
[0:a]pan=mono|c0=c11[a11];\
[0:a]pan=mono|c0=c12[a12];\
[0:a]pan=mono|c0=c13[a13];\
[0:a]pan=mono|c0=c14[a14];\
[0:a]pan=mono|c0=c15[a15];\
[0:a]pan=mono|c0=c16[a16];\
[a0][a1][a2][a3][a4][a5][a6][a7][a8][a9][a10][a11][a12][a13][a14][a15][a16]amerge=inputs=17"
```

Comment: cool that seems to work. the actual filter i'm using is `"$(seq -s';' -f '[0:a]pan=mono|c%g' 0 $((channels-1)) | sed -e 's|c\([0-9]*\)|c0=c\1[a\1]|g');$(seq -f "[a%g]" -s "" 0 $((channels-1)))amerge=inputs=${channels}"`

Comment: Thank you @aergistal for the input. I had to modify it because [0:a] only had c0, so I could not use c1,c2, and so forth. The trick was to use [0:a:0] [0:a:1] and so forth, and pan=mono=c0 for every channel.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer from @aergistal, and working with an mxf file with 10 audio streams, I had to modify the filter in order to specify the input to every pan filter. Working with "pan=mono" it only uses one channel identified as c0

```
-filter_complex "\
[0:a:0]pan=mono|c0=c0[a0];\
[0:a:1]pan=mono|c0=c0[a1];\
[0:a:2]pan=mono|c0=c0[a2];\
[0:a:3]pan=mono|c0=c0[a3];\
[0:a:4]pan=mono|c0=c0[a4];\
[0:a:5]pan=mono|c0=c0[a5];\
[0:a:6]pan=mono|c0=c0[a6];\
[0:a:7]pan=mono|c0=c0[a7];\
[0:a:8]pan=mono|c0=c0[a8];\
[0:a:9]pan=mono|c0=c0[a9];\
[a0][a1][a2][a3][a4][a5][a6][a7][a8][a9]amerge=inputs=10"
```

Answer (score 0):

just for the record (and because i was asked on a side-channel).

this is what still works for me (using @aergistal's answer), extracting (e.g.) the first 25 channels from the `input.wav` file and storing the result in `output25.wav`:

```bash
outchannels=25
ffmpeg -y \
  -i input.wav \
  -filter_complex  "$(seq -s';' -f '[0:a]pan=mono|c%g' 0 $((outchannels-1)) | sed -e 's|c\([0-9]*\)|c0=c\1[a\1]|g');$(seq -f "[a%g]" -s "" 0 $((outchannels-1)))amerge=inputs=${outchannels}" \
  "output${outchannels}.wav"
```